# Import and transform wordpress meta data to ACF repeater field

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I want to transform wp_postmeta data of an old plugin to Advanced Custom Fields ACF (Pro, but that's not the point). The old plugin saved ALL data in ONE meta_value (separated with `||` and `\n`) while ACF would use multiple values:

Old Plugin data in MySQL:

```
meta_id 
post_id    1000
meta_key   "oldplugname"
meta_value "data1||url1\ndata2||url2\ndata3||url3\n"
```

As you can see, I have zero to multiple data<->url per post_id

How would I transform this to an ACF Pro Repeater Field (let's call this field "repeater")?

When trying to build sth. similar with repeater i'd get with 3 data-url :

```
meta_key              -> meta_value

repeaterfield         -> 3
_repeaterfield        -> field_5cdbf84150b2a
repeaterfield_0_data  -> aaa
_repeaterfield_0_data -> field_5cdbf84f50b2b
repeaterfield_0_url   -> http://urlforaaa.com
_repeaterfield_0_url  -> field_5cdbf84f50b2c
repeaterfield_1_data  -> bbb
_repeaterfield_1_data -> field_5cdbf84f50b2b
repeaterfield_1_url   -> http://urlforbbb.com
_repeaterfield_1_url  -> field_5cdbf84f50b2c
repeaterfield_2_data  -> ccc
_repeaterfield_2_data -> field_5cdbf84f50b2b
repeaterfield_2_url   -> http://urlforccc.com
_repeaterfield_2_url  -> field_5cdbf84f50b2c
```

So any idea, how to transform that old data over from "oldplugin" to ACF?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ACF's add_row() method: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/add_row/

Split the old plugin's meta value, first by \n and then by ||, loop through it and for each row use the add_row() method.